# Reading a specific line in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Regardless of how basic this task seems to be I am struggling to read a specific line of a file in Python.

I am creating a quotation system for reading and writing files is a key part. In the code the line which needs to get read needs to correspond to a place value predefined by the variable `Position`. I then want the line to be stored to a variable.

I am trying to look for an efficient way where you don't have to go through the whole file. I have tried using `file.readline(Position)` but that keeps displaying 0. I have included parts of my code for context.

```
value = self.option.get()
Position= int(array.index(value))
print(value) #test
print(Position) #test

file= open("Height_File.txt", "r")
Height= file.readline(Position)
print(Height)#test
file.close()
```

Comment: You are trying to take a spesific line from the file right ? Or are you trying to take a **part** of the next line ?

Comment: Are you going to be continually accessing different lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a specific line from a file you can use the [linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) module's `linecache.getline` function.

Demo:

Suppose your file is named testfile.txt and has the content

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Then you would access line2 with

```
>>> import linecache
>>> linecache.getline('testfile.txt', 2)
'line2\n'
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I stand corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an even better way, but off the top of my head, this will use an iterator, so it will be more efficient than above for just reading one line.

```py
def read_line(path, line_number, encoding=None):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == line_number:
                yield line.strip('\r\n')
```

Note, to call, you would do:

    next(read_line(path, line_number))

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this.

```
Height = file.readlines()[position]
```

This gives you the line with the position you enter(starting from 0)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't realize he was asking about python3.